# Pyspark write JSON column to Postgres using AWS Glue

Tags: python, postgresql, apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

I have the following data frame (df4):

```
+------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
|id                                  |exclusion_reason                          |created_at                |updated_at                |
+------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
|4c01d951-2ec5-4ba4-bfe2-8ba9c3029962|{"ship_reason": "A1", "bill_reason": "A1"}|2021-01-12 16:04:19.673197|2021-01-12 16:04:19.694706|
|dac14ca3-bf44-4e3c-80e8-0e2d6d2ff576|{"ship_reason": "A1", "bill_reason": "A1"}|2021-01-12 16:04:19.673197|2021-01-12 16:04:19.694706|
|6d277012-ff6c-4202-bbd7-64cbd467ca28|{"ship_reason": "A1", "bill_reason": "A1"}|2021-01-12 16:04:19.673197|2021-01-12 16:04:19.694706|
|0388163e-2614-4b71-b707-623337d58387|{"ship_reason": "A1", "bill_reason": "A1"}|2021-01-12 16:04:19.673197|2021-01-12 16:04:19.694706|
|01daec52-408c-44e3-965a-b87daa334a1a|{"ship_reason": "A1", "bill_reason": "A1"}|2021-01-12 16:04:19.673197|2021-01-12 16:04:19.694706|
+------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
```

that I need to write to a Postgres database. I am using AWS Glue and the Postgres database is in a VPC, so I need to do so using a glue connection and the `glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_jdbc_conf` method. The issue is that I keep getting the error `ERROR: column "matchback_exclusion_reason" is of type jsonb but expression is of type character`. The data type in the data frame is string, and the datatype in the database is JSONB.

I have seen suggestions that I just need to add `stringtype: "unspecified"` to my write statement, but the following produces the same error:

```
datasource2 = DynamicFrame.fromDF(df4, glueContext, "ParquetToWrite")

output = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_jdbc_conf(frame = datasource2, catalog_connection = "MPtest", connection_options = {"stringtype":"unspecified", "database" : "app", "dbtable" : "orders"})
```

Can I cast this column to a JSON somehow? I have tried creating a struct type to parse the elements, but that didnt work either (code below):

```
schema = StructType([StructField("ship_reason", StringType()),StructField("bill_reason", StringType())])
df4Test.select(f.from_json(df4.exclusion_reason, schema).alias("exclusion_reason"))

df4Test = df4Test.withColumn("exclusion_reason", f.from_json(df4.exclusion_reason, schema).alias("exclusion_reason"))
```

Is it possible to modify the column type to be a JSONB type? Ideally I would basically just like to "`json.load`" the exclusion_reason column so I can write it to Postgres.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`ResolveChoice`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-transforms-ResolveChoice.html) may help by casting `exclusion_reason` to `json`:

`datasource3 = datasource2.resolveChoice(specs = [('exclusion_reason','cast:json')])`

From [AWS Glue Developer Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/built-in-transforms.html)

> Use `ResolveChoice` to specify how a column should be handled when it
> contains values of multiple types. You can choose to either cast the
> column to a single data type, discard one or more of the types, or
> retain all types in either separate columns or a structure. You can
> select a different resolution policy for each column or specify a
> global policy that is applied to all columns.